# Android creates new application instance

Tags: android, lifecycle

I have an application with number of activities. Own Application class is used for storing global data, so any activity may retrieve it.
The problem is when I'am walking hard through activities (especially through activities that creates a lot of bitmap images) system creates new instance of Application class with incorrect global data.

The question is: why this happens? )

I believe that there are some simple explanation of such behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the `android:launchMode` attribute inside your `activity` tag in androidManifest.xml to fit your needs, like:

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTask" [...]>
    [...]
</activity>
```

You can read more about it:
[android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" | "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

> "singleTask" and "singleInstance"
>   activities can only begin a task. They
>   are always at the root of the activity
>   stack. Moreover, the device can hold
>   only one instance of the activity at a
>   time — only one such task.
>
> The `"singleTask"` and `"singleInstance"`
>   modes differ from each other in only
>   one respect: A "singleTask" activity
>   allows other activities to be part of
>   its task. It's always at the root of
>   its task, but other activities
>   (necessarily "standard" and
>   `"singleTop"` activities) can be
>   launched into that task. A
>   `"singleInstance"` activity, on the
>   other hand, permits no other
>   activities to be part of its task.
>   It's the only activity in the task. If
>   it starts another activity, that
>   activity is assigned to a different
>   task — as if `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`
>   was in the intent.

This way you can be sure that you'll have only one instance of your activity running.

Comment: Does singleTask guarantee that Application.onCreate method calls once?
Or there are possible situation when system decides to kill some objects and 'recreate' application instance?

Comment: If your application (activity in the UI thread) is running, the system won't clean up anything related to it. That's why services (that are not running in the UI thread most of the cases) use a notification icon, to prevent the gc from collecting their resources... You should read the link above.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the original question. In which way are tasks related to multiple instances of the Application class?